# Can't read appsettings after update

Tags: c#, .net-core, console, appsettings

How app works:

Option 1 - Load itens from appsettings
Option 2 - Include a new item

If select "Option 1", show itens. It work.
So... i include a new item using "Option 2". It work.
But if i select "Option 1" to show itens, the list is empty.

My appsettings

```
  "app": {
    "hosts": [
      {
        "ip": "127.0.0.1",
        "hostname": "NotFound"
      },
      {
        "ip": "127.0.0.1",
        "hostname": "MyProject"
      },
      {
        "ip": "127.0.0.1",
        "hostname": "AnotherProject.dev"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Make a bind

```
AppSettingsModel appSettings = new AppSettingsModel();
Configuration.Bind("app", appSettings);
```

I configure appsettings to reloadOnChange

```
static IConfiguration LoadConfiguration() => 
            new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
                .Build();
```

Update a appsettings

```
var appSettings = new AppSettingsModel();
                        var appSettings = new AppSettingsModel();
Configuration.Bind("app", appSettings);

appSettings.Hosts.Add(new HostsModel()
{ 
    Ip = "102.54.94.97",
    Hostname = "rhino.acme.com" 
});

var jsonSerializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
};

var resultC = JsonSerializer.Serialize(appSettings, jsonSerializerOptions);

File.WriteAllText("appsettings.json", resultC);
```

My code -> https://github.com/tiago-aguiar-moreira/ManagerHosts

Comment: is it .netcore console app or .netcore wpf ?

Comment: I'm using.netcore 3

Comment: Ok, does the below answer your question?

Comment: No, actually my problem is to load appsettings. The problem is to bind the file with the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was entering a section in the Bind method, but it was not necessary in my case.

Before

Configuration.Bind("hosts", appSettings);

After

Configuration.Bind(appSettings);